# First Order Logic: Everybody has an initial position

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I'm having difficulty expressing the following thought in first order logic.

I want to say that every agent has an initial position and I'd express it as this (using words):

> For All agent of type Agents, There Exists an x of type xCoordinate and an y of type yCoordinate such that I_Position(agent,x,y) AND Tile(x,y)

Or in idp:

```
!ag[agent]: ? xCo[xCo],yCo[yCo]: I_position(ag, xCo, yCo) & Tile(xCo,yCo).
```

With tile being an expression for a valid tile, a valid position.

Problem with this expression is that I've been learned that an `For All` expression is ALWAYS with an implication (`=>`) and a `There Exists` expression is always with an And (`&`).

Obviously, I don't have an implication. Does this sentence do what I think it does?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood what your teacher/textbook was saying. It is meaningful to write a sentence with a universal quantifier ("for all") but no implication operator. In a conceptual sense there is always an implicit implication but it is not usually written with an explicit implication operator. Even your statement can be expressed as an implication like this: "IF something is an agent THEN it will have an initial position." Similarly, at a conceptual level, the existential quantifier expresses an implicit conjunction: "There exists a tile AND that tile has a particular position."